# Yii2: How to remove required attribute with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, required, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a textInput **field** that is required but when the **checkbox** is pressed the field is not require.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?= Html::checkbox('myCheckbox', false, ['id' => 'myCheckbox']) ?>
        I don't send my address
    </label>
</div>

<?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'address']) ?>
```

I need to remove the required attribute when the user checks the checkbox. I think jQuery is the best approach so I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$("#myCheckbox").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#address").prop("required", "false");
    }
    else {
        $("#address").prop("required", "true");
    }
});
```

I can see that the **required attribute** is not on the input tag, it is in his parent tag:

```
<div class="form-group field-address required has-success">
    <label class="control-label" for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" name="Form[address]" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

    <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using `when` and `whenClient` options? is it compulsary to show the field when not required.

Comment: 1- `required` from your html code is a class not an attribute .. 2- if you need to change input `aria-required="true"` you'll need `$("#address").attr("aria-required", "false");` .. 3- if you need to remove the class you can use `$("#address").parent().removeClass("required");`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not using `when` and `whenClient` options? change the checkbox to a model field, declare a public property with the name `myCheckbox`

```
public $myCheckbox
```

inside the `Form` Model then change the following.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?= Html::checkbox('myCheckbox', false, ['id' => 'myCheckbox']) ?>
        I don't send my address
    </label>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <?= $form->field($model,'myCheckbox')->checkbox(['uncheck'=>null,'id'=>'myCheckbox']) ?>
        I don't send my address
    </label>
</div>
```

then inside your rules in the `Form` Model do the following

```
['address' , 'required' , 'when' => function($model) {
                    return ($model->myCheckbox!==null);
                } , 'whenClient' => 'function(attribute,value){return ($("#myCheckbox:checked").length>0)}' ] ,
```

Hope it helps you out

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked for me, it also gave me an idea on how I can manipulate model rules dynamically.

Comment: you are welcome @ThatoPebane . you can always show some love with an up-vote :P